# Old Systems..and My Clients

Tags: 12.04

I have some 500+ installs of Lubuntu and Xubuntu on processors from Pentium II (400 mgh) to AMD (1 gh P. III equiv.) and I need to know if 14.04 will run in place of 12.04. Most will not cleanly load 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

Without a full explanation of what the problems are in 13.10 it is very hard to give a mores specific answer than this:

There is no reason why 14.04 will run better than 13.10 for your computers, it is not that they put more effort into LTS versions, just that they update and support them for longer. The best solution is to use a test machine to try 14.04 to see if you have issues and if not stick to 12.04, it is supported until 2017. By this point 14.04 will be a lot older and more issue with old hardware will be ironed out. Perhaps try 14.04 again in 2015 if it doesn't work initially.

Answer (score 0):

I have an old machine that runs Lubuntu 13.04 well, but not 13.10. My problem (and perhaps yours) is that there is not yet an [Intel Graphics Installer](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.2-linux) for 13.10, so most videos would not play. I'd look carefully at your hardware and see if this will be a problem for some of your systems.

Comment: I'm aware of the Video driver issues. I was hoping the 14.04 would fix the issues with MESA and Some older NVDIA (NV and Neavou installs. The time to do it manually with each upgrade would be expensive for my small company. I'm more concerned with the kernel and these older processors.

Comment: I understand . . . I maintain maybe eight systems for the family, and that's a pain with the different versions of Ubuntu they prefer and the different hardware. With hundreds to maintain, I expect you **need** a standard set-up that really runs the first time, every time.